# Perl Plack session Resource temporarily unavailable at error

Tags: perl, ubuntu-16.04, mojolicious

While using Mojolicious Framework I am getting `can't get shared lock on /data/app/tmp/sessions/40dea635eadfeada5993 Resource temporarily unavailable at /usr/share/perl5/Plack/Session/Store/File.pm line 27.`

The perl line

```
$params{'serializer'}   ||= sub { Storable::lock_nstore( @_ ) };
$params{'deserializer'} ||= sub { Storable::lock_retrieve( @_ ) }; <--- line 27
```

It doesn't happen all of time.  But once I start getting the error.  I have to restart the application for the server to go away.  It doesn't always clear the error.

Comment: What kind of Plack server are you using?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean,But I installed the perl module `Plack` and the following Plack modules `App,Handler,HTTPParser,Loader,Middleware,Request,Session,Test and Util`.  Nginx is the web server.

Comment: I am also using `Starman`

Comment: It means the call to `flock` returned error `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`. The later is unlikely since `LOCK_NB` isn't being used. And I don't know what would cause it to return `EAGAIN`.